# Can we make a software that markets a artist to their audience?

Tags: halal-haram, music, software

Can we make a software that markets a artist to their audience?
Currently we got a request to create a software that will be used by artists in music and video sector to market their albums and promote themselves using different technologies, SMS being one of them.

Is it allowed in Islam to create or assist is such project?
The project payment we get, will it be halal or haram?

Answer (score 2):

Being a software engineer, i am also now days having an offer of a related project, and i am trying my best to avoid it, and i believe supporting any sin is as bad as the sin itself...

And ALlah says in Quran:

> "Indeed, those who like that immorality(فواحش) should be spread [or
>   publicized] among believers will have a painful
>   punishment in this world and the Hereafter. And Allah knows and you do
>   not know." Quran 24:19

(quoted above verse in context that by publicity of that music and those artists, most probably, will spread fahash(immoral) music/songs etc, and most muslims sects consider music haraam, so...)

And i would not say its haram or not, but i would say it will add sins in your ACCOUNT too, and it's far better to avoid such things. I know in our industry, there are about half of the projects which are somehow supporting things like these, but as muslims, we have to avoid them whatsoever.

Comment: How did the 24:19 interpretation went from "..WILL [a promise from God] have a painful punishment in this world and the Hereafter" to "deserve a painful punishment/chastisement..." The second part of the verse explains it:" And Allah knows AND you do not know." and I do speak Arabic and the verse you provided is wrongly translated. Please be careful.

Comment: i din't translated this verse, i also knwo arabic, but i didn't checked, i just picked one from quran.com, you can point out the error in translation or edit it yourself.